# Combination or Permutation

Tags: permutations, combinations

Q.1)"Find the no. of  ways in which $5$ boys and $3$ girls can be seated in a row so that no two girls are together."

Q.2)"In how many ways can $5$ white balls and $3$ black balls are arranged in arow so that no two black balls are together?"

My textbook solved the first question with the concept of permutation while solved the second one with the concept of combination.

The two questions seem extremely similar.Then,why two different concepts are used?

Comment: The difference is whether the objects are distinguishable, and as both of them appear frequently, we introduce two concepts respectively.

Comment: I get it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is not explicitly stated, it is assumed that all the people are different from each other, while the balls are not (at least in the sense the only attribute we care about for the balls is whether they are black or white).

Still, the concepts are closely related, and the answer to the first problem should be $5!3!=720$ times as many as the answer to the second problem, because for each valid arrangement of white and black balls, we have $5!3!=720$ valid arrangements of people (we just permute the places the boys and girls can sit).